# $scope is only visible in function and thats why is not working

Tags: angularjs

My layout page looks like this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="../Account/#/PersonalInfo" ng-click="SetActiveMenuForPersonalInfo();">@Translate("MY_ACCOUNT")</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

In layout page i have : `@RenderBody()`where i have Index page.In index page im using `<div ng-view></div>`. What im trying to do is when user click on a href to redirect him on that page and set class to this menu that is render in ng-view:

```
<div class="account-item">
<div class="account-heading" ng-class="{active : activeMenu === 'Settings'}">
<h4 class=" account-title has-sub">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#settings" ng-click="activeMenu='Settings'">5. @Translate("SETTINGS")</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="settings" class="account-collapse collapse in">
<div class="account-body">
<a href="#/PersonalInfo" ng-class="{'active-link' : activeLink==='PersonalInfo'}" ng-click="activeLink='PersonalInfo'">@Translate("PERSONAL_INFORMATION")</a>
<a href="#/Notifications" ng-class="{'active-link' : activeLink==='Notifications'}" ng-click="activeLink='Notifications'">@Translate("NOTIFICATIONS")</a>
<a href="#/PasswordChange" ng-class="{'active-link' : activeLink=='PasswordChange'}" ng-click="activeLink = 'PasswordChange'">@Translate("CHANGE_PASSWORD")</a>
<a href="#">@Translate("GAME_SETTINGS")</a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

When i try this nothing happens:

```
 $scope.SetActiveMenuForPersonalInfo = function () {

        $scope.activeMenu = 'Settings';
        $scope.activeLink = "PersonalInfo";

    }
```

`$scope.activeMenu` and `$scope.activeLink` are visible only in function and thats why i cant set class on menu. When i put it out of function it works

Comment: You should use ng-href instead of native href. Like this `ng-href="PasswordChange"` instead of `href="#/PasswordChange"`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tripple equality sign in `ng-class="{'active-link' : activeLink==='PersonalInfo'}"` to double `==`

PS: I do not understand the last paragraph

Comment: i have controller and when i use $scope.activeMenu = "Settings"; i get class on menu but when i put that in function on ng-click then its not working

Comment: Hmmm... probably that function is defined in different scope. Or the DOM node is assigned to different scope than you would except. You can easily check the scope variables in browser console via command `angular.element($0).scope()` where $0 is the last inspected element in DOM inspector

Comment: `where $0 is the last inspected element in DOM inspector` more about it here https://coderwall.com/p/8ijbjq/js-console-trick-use-0-to-access-inspected-element or more verbose here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: im not sure that i understand u

Comment: Ok, so create an example in Plunkr or something similar

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/gJko3umteXXEye7o9StR?p=preview  there...and now when user click on layout page to get selected on index page

Comment: By clicking the link ichange view, thus re-instantiating mycontroller. This is why the activeMenu is empty.